# ERROR: No matching distribution found for jax[gpu]>=0.3.4 (from -r vit_jax/requirements.txt (line 8))

Tags: dockerfile, jax

trying to build my first dockerfile for vision transformer. ran into

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> jax[gpu]>=0.3.4 (from -r vit_jax/requirements.txt (line 8)) (from
> versions: 0.0, 0.1, 0.1.1, 0.1.2, 0.1.3, 0.1.4, 0.1.5, 0.1.6, 0.1.7,
> 0.1.8, 0.1.9, 0.1.10, 0.1.11, 0.1.12, 0.1.13, 0.1.14, 0.1.15, 0.1.16, 0.1.18, 0.1.19, 0.1.20, 0.1.21, 0.1.22, 0.1.23, 0.1.24, 0.1.25, 0.1.26, 0.1.27, 0.1.28, 0.1.29, 0.1.30, 0.1.31, 0.1.32, 0.1.33, 0.1.34, 0.1.35, 0.1.36, 0.1.37, 0.1.38, 0.1.39, 0.1.40, 0.1.41, 0.1.42, 0.1.43, 0.1.44, 0.1.45, 0.1.46, 0.1.47, 0.1.48, 0.1.49, 0.1.50, 0.1.51, 0.1.52, 0.1.53, 0.1.54, 0.1.55, 0.1.56, 0.1.57, 0.1.58, 0.1.59, 0.1.60, 0.1.61, 0.1.62, 0.1.63, 0.1.64, 0.1.65, 0.1.66, 0.1.67, 0.1.68, 0.1.69, 0.1.70, 0.1.71, 0.1.72, 0.1.73, 0.1.74, 0.1.75, 0.1.76, 0.1.77, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.3, 0.2.4, 0.2.5, 0.2.6, 0.2.7, 0.2.8, 0.2.9, 0.2.10, 0.2.11, 0.2.12, 0.2.13, 0.2.14, 0.2.15, 0.2.16, 0.2.17) ERROR: No matching distribution found for jax[gpu]>=0.3.4 (from -r vit_jax/requirements.txt (line 8))

didn't find anyone running vit ran into this problem, so i assume it's my dockerfile's flaw not requirements.txt's? below is my dockerfile

```
FROM pytorch/pytorch:1.2-cuda10.0-cudnn7-runtime

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ARG USERNAME=user
WORKDIR /dockertest
ARG WORKDIR=/dockertest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        automake autoconf libpng-dev nano python3-pip \
        sudo curl zip unzip libtool swig zlib1g-dev pkg-config \
        python3-mock libpython3-dev libpython3-all-dev \
        g++ gcc cmake make pciutils cpio gosu wget \
        libgtk-3-dev libxtst-dev sudo apt-transport-https \
        build-essential gnupg git xz-utils vim libgtk2.0-0 libcanberra-gtk-module\
        libva-dev libdrm-dev xorg xorg-dev protobuf-compiler \
        openbox libx11-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dev \
        libtbb2 libtbb-dev libopenblas-dev libopenmpi-dev \
    && sed -i 's/# set linenumbers/set linenumbers/g' /etc/nanorc \
    && apt clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN git clone https://github.com/google-research/vision_transformer.git \
    &&cd vision_transformer \
    && pip3 install pip --upgrade \
    && pip install -r vit_jax/requirements.txt \
    &&python -m vit_jax.main --workdir=/tmp/vit-$(date +%s) \
    --config=$(pwd)/vit_jax/configs/vit.py:b16,cifar10 \
    --config.pretrained_dir='gs://vit_models/imagenet21k' \
    && pip cache purge

RUN echo "root:root" | chpasswd \
    && adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" "${USERNAME}" \
    && echo "${USERNAME}:${USERNAME}" | chpasswd \
    && echo "%${USERNAME}    ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD:    ALL" >> /etc/sudoers.d/${USERNAME} \
    && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/${USERNAME}
USER ${USERNAME}
RUN sudo chown -R ${USERNAME}:${USERNAME} ${WORKDIR}
WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using Python 3.6 (as specified in the [docker file](https://hub.docker.com/layers/pytorch/pytorch/1.2-cuda10.0-cudnn7-runtime/images/sha256-c8d372e59b86104cf1ffa859b58fada30248a9689cd6e446d06134c9bad52e77)), which is not supported by JAX version 0.2.18 and newer (see [JAX Changelog](https://github.com/google/jax/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#jax-0218-july-21-2021)).

To fix the issue, you should upgrade Python to version 3.7 or newer. Python 3.6 has reached its [end of life](https://endoflife.date/python) and is no longer receiving security updates.

Alternatively, if for some reason you must continue using Python 3.6, you should install jax version 0.2.17 and jaxlib version 0.1.69, which were the last releases to be compatible with Python 3.6.

Comment: it does fix the error when i change it to 1.8.1-cuda10.2-cudnn7-runtime, i remembered i changed to older version due to another error, but that error didnt show up this time.